# SQS Encryption - Why does SNS need to use KMS CMK but Lambda don't for associated SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

I'm turning on SSE for two SQS queues.

The first queue is subscribed to an SNS and has a lambda trigger.
The second queue doesn't have SNS subscription and only has a lambda trigger.

It seems I can use the default AWS managed key `aws/sqs` for the 2nd queue without giving the lambda execution role permissions to the key. However, for the first queue, as [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-topic-sqs-queue-sse-kms-key-policy/) AWS page suggests, I need to use a Customer-managed key.

My questions is why do I need a customer-managed key with an extra key policy to allow SNS to access the encrypted SQS but I don't need it for lambda to access the encrypted SQS?